# Why does my vertex shader ignore Uint8Array data but not Float32Array data?

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, webgl, twgl.js

My vertex shader has the following attribute:

```c
attribute float a_color;
```

I have an array buffer (WebAssembly's memory) which consists only of 0s and 1s and I create a view of it by creating a `Uint8Array`. However my vertex shader ignores it (no errors, but seems to treat everything as 0). I am using `twgl`. Here's my code:

Vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute float a_color;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_point_width;
varying vec4 v_color;

vec2 normalize_coords(vec2 position) {
   float x = position[0];
   float y = position[1];
   float resx = u_resolution[0];
   float resy = u_resolution[1];
   return vec2(2.0 * x / resx - 1.0, 2.0 * y / resy - 1.0);
}

void main() {
   gl_PointSize = u_point_width;
   vec2 coords = normalize_coords(a_position);
   gl_Position = vec4(coords * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
   v_color = vec4(0, a_color ,0,1);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```c
precision highp float;

varying vec4 v_color;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
  const canvas = document.getElementById("c");

  const CELL_SIZE = 10;

  const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [
    "vertex-shader",
    "fragment-shader"
  ]);

  twgl.setDefaults({ attribPrefix: "a_" });

  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas, window.devicePixelRatio);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  const universe = Universe.new(
    Math.ceil(gl.canvas.width / CELL_SIZE / 2),
    Math.ceil(gl.canvas.height / CELL_SIZE / 2)
  );
  const width = universe.width();
  const height = universe.height();

  let points = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      points.push([i * CELL_SIZE * 2, j * CELL_SIZE * 2]);
    }
  }

  const cellsPtr = universe.cells();
  // Webassembly memory (only 0's and 1's)
  const cells = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, cellsPtr, width * height);

  const arrays = {
    position: {
      data: new Float32Array(points.flat()),
      size: 2
    },
    color: {
      data: cells,
      size: 1,
      type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE
    }
  };

  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

  const uniforms = {
    u_resolution: [gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height],
    u_point_width: CELL_SIZE
  };

  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);

  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo, gl.POINTS);

  function renderLoop(time) {
    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas, window.devicePixelRatio);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    universe.tick();
    const cellsPtr = universe.cells();
    const cells = new Uint8Array(
      memory.buffer,
      cellsPtr,
      width * height
    );

    const uniforms = {
      u_resolution: [gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height],
      u_point_width: CELL_SIZE
    };

    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);

    twgl.setAttribInfoBufferFromArray(gl, bufferInfo.attribs.a_color, {
      data: cells,
      size: 1,
      type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE
    }); // Dynamically update buffer with new colors

    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo, gl.POINTS);
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
};
```

I have no problems if I manually convert `cells` to `Float32Array`. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's a live simplified version of the code above (there should be green points on the screen but there aren't):

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-jackson-ut3wm

Comment: Try `gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_color_location, 1, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, true, 0, 0);` setting normalized to true so that the type is normalized

Comment: You need to post more code **in the question itself**. @Blindman67's comment irrelavent as you pointed out your're putting 0s and 1s in your array. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/sd6pkvqx/

Comment: @gman Yeah, I should have done that. I edited my question. Here's a simplified example on Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-jackson-ut3wm

Comment: I'll add that I tried changing Uint8Array to Uint8ClampedArray and it seems to work as I expect but only in Chrome and not Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually are using twgl then, in the same way that it guesses size = 3 for position, 4 for colors, 2 for texcoords, the issue that twgl is guessing to use `normalize: true` and you need to tell it `normalize: false`

From [the docs](http://twgljs.org/docs/module-twgl.html#.FullArraySpec)

> `normalize`   boolean --- 
>   normalize for `vertexAttribPointer`. Default is `true` if type is `Int8Array` or `Uint8Array` otherwise `false`.

So,

```
  const arrays = {
    position: {
      data: new Float32Array(points.flat()),
      size: 2
    },
    color: {
      data: cells,
      size: 1,
      type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
      normalize: false,       // added <------------------------
    }
  };
```

BTW: if `cells` is a `Uint8Array` then you don't need `type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE`. twgl will set type to `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` based on the fact that the data is `Uint8Array`.

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using is not consistently defaulting `undefined` properties. Setting `normalized` to `true` along some path for `Uint8Array` and `Int8Array` array types.

### Normalizing the attribute buffer data

The normalize argument if `true` in [`WebGLRenderingContext.vertexAttribPointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttribPointer) will normalize integer within a unit range. For signed -1 to 1 and for unsigned 0 to 1.

This results in the `color` attribute is set to `1 / 255` when you use an array of type `Uint8Array` and don`t define the value of`normalized`

You can scale the value back to 1 in the vertex shader.

Example vertex shader

```
attribute float color;

//... code

varying vec4 colorOut;
void main() {

    // ... code

    colorOut = vec4(0, color * 255.0, 0, 1);  // scale the color by 255
}
```

### Example

Showing how `normalized` changes attribute data. The red is is not normalized and the green is. Note that this does not use any library.

```js
const GL_OPTIONS = {alpha: false, depth: false, premultpliedAlpha: false, preserveDrawingBufer: true};
const CELL_SIZE = 10, GRID_SIZE = 32, GRID_PX_WIDTH = GRID_SIZE * CELL_SIZE, CELLS = GRID_SIZE ** 2;
const GL_SETUP = {
    get context() { return  canvas.getContext("webgl", GL_OPTIONS) },
    get locations() { return ["A_pos", "A_green", "A_red", "U_res"] },  
    get vertex() { return `
attribute vec2 pos;
attribute float green;
attribute float red;
uniform vec2 res;
varying vec4 colorV;
void main() {
    gl_PointSize = ${(CELL_SIZE - 2).toFixed(1)};
    gl_Position = vec4(pos / res, 0, 1);
    colorV = vec4(red, green * 255.0, 0, 1);
}`;
    },
    get fragment() { return `
precision highp float;
varying vec4 colorV;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = colorV;
}`;
    },
    get buffers() {
        return {
            pos: { buffer: GL_SETUP.grid },
            red: { size: 1, type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalize: false, buffer: GL_SETUP.colorsRed },
            green: { size: 1, type: gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, normalize: true, buffer: GL_SETUP.colorsGreen }
        };
    },
    get grid() {
        var i = CELLS, buf = new Float32Array(i * 2), idx;
        while (i--) {
            idx = i << 1;
            buf[idx++]  = (i % GRID_SIZE) * CELL_SIZE - GRID_PX_WIDTH / 2;
            buf[idx] = (i / GRID_SIZE | 0) * CELL_SIZE - GRID_PX_WIDTH / 2;
        }
        return buf;
    },
    get colorsRed() {
        var i = CELLS, buf = new Uint8Array(i);
        while(i--) { buf[i] = Math.random() < 0.5 && i < CELLS / 2 ? 1 : 0 }
        return buf; 
    },    
    get colorsGreen() {
        var i = CELLS, buf = new Uint8Array(i);
        while(i--) { buf[i] = Math.random() < 0.5 && i >= CELLS / 2 ? 1 : 0 }
        return buf; 
    },    
};

const gl = GL_SETUP.context;
const shader = initShader(gl, GL_SETUP);
const W = canvas.width = innerWidth, H = canvas.height = innerHeight;
gl.viewport(0, 0, W, H);
gl.uniform2fv(shader.locations.res, new Float32Array([W / 2 , -H / 2]));
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, CELLS);

function compileAndAttach(gl, program, src, type = gl.VERTEX_SHADER) {
    const shader = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, src);
    gl.compileShader(shader);   
    gl.attachShader(program, shader);
}
function createShader(gl, settings) {
    const locations = {}, program = gl.createProgram();
    compileAndAttach(gl, program, settings.vertex);
    compileAndAttach(gl, program, settings.fragment, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    for(const desc of settings.locations) {
        const [type, name] = desc.split("_");
        locations[name] = gl[`get${type==="A" ? "Attrib" : "Uniform"}Location`](program, name);
    }
    return {program, locations, gl};
}
function initShader(gl, settings) {
    const shader = createShader(gl, settings);
    for (const [name, data] of Object.entries(settings.buffers)) {
        const {use = gl.STATIC_DRAW, type = gl.FLOAT, buffer, size = 2, normalize = false} = data;
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, use);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shader.locations[name]);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader.locations[name], size, type, normalize, 0, 0);
    }
    return shader;
}
```

```css
body { padding: 0px }
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I'm still not sure what this answer has to do with the question asked. The questioner didn't want normalized values. As for the library. It does the most common thing which is that unsigned byte data is normalized. You call that inconstistent, I call it convenient which is exactly that the library is designed for.